# Como obter um item de um list randomicamente?

Tags: python, lista, random

Suponhamos que eu tenha a seguinte lista:

```
frutas = ['abacate', 'mamão', 'laranja', 'uva', 'pêra']
```

Eu preciso capturar um desses elementos da `list` randomicamente.

Como eu faria isso em Python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Resposta* [SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/306417/6797930), use o [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice)

```
import random

frutas = ['abacate', 'mamão', 'laranja', 'uva', 'pêra']
print(random.choice(frutas))
```

[***Exemplo Online***](http://ideone.com/Ur1zgc)

<sub>***Referencia:***</sub>

- [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice)

Answer (score 5):

Considerando que é possível usar o `random.choice`, por outro lado, caso queira também capturar vários itens randomicamente, você pode usar `random.sample` passando como parâmetro a lista e a quantidade de itens a mostrar. Veja:

**random.choice()**

```
import random
print(random.choice(['abacate', 'mamão', 'laranja', 'uva', 'pêra']))
```

**random.sample()**

```
import random    
print(random.sample(['abacate', 'mamão', 'laranja', 'uva', 'pêra'],  3))
```

Saiba mais sobre outro métodos do módulo `random` [na documentação](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html).

Comment: Legal o complemento. Como no PHP tem as duas formas. Saber disso em Python também é bom +1

Comment: Muito bom, a saída fica assim escolhendo 2 utilizando o random.sample: `['pêra', 'uva'] ` Tem como formatar essa saída sem ter que atribuí-la a outra variável? Para ter uma saída assim por exemplo: `pêra, uva`.