# Como fazer um sorteio infinito de nomes em PYTHON?

Tags: python

Estou tentando mas ele só está printando a primeira letra do último nome escolhido. Gostaria que sorteasse um nome aleatório.

```
    import random
    alunos = 0
    sorteio = 0
    while alunos != '0':
alunos = str(input(
    'Vamos descobrir quem é o aluno sorteado. (digite 0 para parar o sorteio). Digite o nome da pessoa: '))
      if alunos != '0':
    sorteio = random.choice(alunos)
    print(sorteio, 'é o sorteado!!!')
```

Comment: Seria legal você [edit] sua pergunta, arrumar a indentação do seu código e também explicar o que você quer dizer com sorteio infinito, pois não faz sentido receber 1 aluno e fazer um sorteio nessa amostra de 1 aluno e repetir isso infinitamente. Você precisa acumular uma amostra de alunos e só depois fazer sorteio. Até entender isso fica muito difícil responder qualquer coisa de qualidade na sua pergunta.

Comment: [Esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/176233/6333) pergunta e [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/477768/6333) podem ajudar a entender sorteio em Python. Ou faça uma [pesquisa no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bpython%5d%20random).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```py
import random
alunos = []
sorteio = 0
while True:
    aluno = str(input('Vamos descobrir quem é o aluno sorteado. (digite 0 para parar o sorteio). Digite o nome da pessoa: '))
    if aluno == '0':
        break
    else:
        alunos.append(aluno)
if alunos != '0':
    sorteio = random.choice(alunos)
    print(sorteio, 'é o sorteado!!!')


Teste2

import random
alunos = []
sorteio = 0
c = -1
while True:
    aluno = str(input('Vamos descobrir quem é o aluno sorteado. (digite 0 para parar o sorteio). Digite o nome da pessoa: '))
    if aluno == '0':
        break
    else:
        alunos.append(aluno)
        c += 1

if alunos != '0':
    sorteio = alunos[random.randint(0, c)]
    print(sorteio, 'é o sorteado!!!')
```

Tente usar o método randint.O jeito usado antes estava funcionando aqui.

Comment: Boa tarde, primeiro obrigado pela resposta.
Tentei dessa forma mas só está puxando o ultimo nome, não está randômico. 
Teria alguma ideia?

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
alunos = []
novo_aluno = "Ninguem"
sorteado = "sortudo"
while novo_aluno != "0":
    novo_aluno = str(input('Vamos descobrir quem é o aluno sorteado. (digite 0 para parar o sorteio). Digite o nome da pessoa: '))
    if novo_aluno == '0':
        break
    alunos.append(novo_aluno)
if alunos != []:
    sorteado = random.choice(alunos)
    print(f"{sorteado} foi o sorteado")
else:
    print("Lista vazia")
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).